# prevent HTML output if custom field is empty

Tags: css, javascript, advanced-custom-fields, html

I am using the ACF plugin for custom fields. I am using this to add a second content area to my website.

I have a peice of JS that says if this div is present then add a class to the page-content div to increase it's size.

js:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(function() {
 jQuery("div.page-content-text-additional").each(function(){
jQuery(this).closest('#container').find("div.page-content").addClass("double");
  });

 });
 </script>
```

HTML:

```
            <div id="container">
                <div class="page-content">
                    <div class="top-menu-page">
                        <div class="logo-page">
                            <div class="draw-logo">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="menu-links">
                    <?php wp_nav_menu( array('top-menu' => 'Top Menu' )); ?>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                // TO SHOW THE PAGE CONTENTS
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> <!--Because the_content() works only inside a WP Loop -->  
                    <div class="page-title">
                    <p class="subs"><span>
            <?php the_field('first_title'); ?>
            </span></p>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="page-content-text">

            <?php
            $first_comment = get_field('first_content_block');
            echo do_shortcode("[vr_jsp] $first_comment [/vr_jsp]");    
            ?> <!-- Page Content -->

                <?php
                endwhile; //resetting the page loop
                wp_reset_query(); //resetting the page query
                ?>


               </div>
                 <?php
                // TO SHOW THE PAGE CONTENTS
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> <!--Because the_content() works only inside a WP Loop --> 

                <div class="page-title-additional">
                    <p class="subs"><span>
            <?php the_field('second_title'); ?>
            </span></p>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="page-content-text-additional">
            <?php
            $second_comment = get_field('second_content_block');
            echo do_shortcode("[vr_jsp] $second_comment [/vr_jsp]");       
            ?> <!-- Page Content -->
               </div>
                <?php
                endwhile; //resetting the page loop
                wp_reset_query(); //resetting the page query
                ?>
               <div class="return-home"><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">Return to home page <strong>X</strong></a></div>
               <br clear="all"/>
               </div>
               </div>
```

My css works but because the div page-content-text-additional renders with or without content the JS puts the double class on regardless. is there a way I am able to only render the page-content-text-additional if there is content in the ACF query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a simple php `if` to check the contents of the field before outputting markup.

```
<?php
if( $second_comment = get_field('second_content_block') ){
    ?>
    <div class="page-content-text-additional">
        <?php echo do_shortcode("[vr_jsp] $second_comment [/vr_jsp]"); ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

You can eliminate the need for adding the class via js using the same method.

Some friendly advice- spending a day reading the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/langref.php) will make your life much easier :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will read the docs before posting on here in future :) My apologies and thank you for the advice.